# Prove that there exist $M$ such that when $|h|$ is sufficiently small, $ \frac{1}{h}\int_a^b|f(x+h)-f(x)|\mathrm{d}x\leq M. $

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

> Suppose $f(x)\in$ BV$([a,b])$(bounded variation). Prove that there exist $M$ such that when $|h|$ is sufficiently small,
> $$
> \dfrac{1}{h}\int_a^b|f(x+h)-f(x)|\mathrm{d}x\leq M.
> $$

By Jordan decomposition, we only need to prove the $f$ increasing case. I know that in this condition, $f$ is differentiable almost every where, and
$$
\int_a^bf'(x)\mathrm{d}x\leq f(b)-f(a).
$$
But I don't know how to proceed.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: How does the integrand $f'(x)$ in your second step relate to the integrand $|f(x + h) - f(x)|/h$ in your first step (for $h$ tiny)?

Comment: How is the integrand defined if $x+h < a$ or $x+h > b$?

Comment: When $x+h<a$, let $f(x)=f(a)$. When $x+h>b$, let $f(x)=f(b)$.

Comment: @prets it seems like an interchange integral and limits problem, but I don't know why it is allowed.

Comment: This is a very good question to ask! Note that the result you're trying to prove isn't a limit ($h$ small but fixed, right?), but it is reminiscent of the expression with a limit you get further down. So try bounding the difference quotient in the original problem in a sensible way to get your result.

Comment: I don't think h is fixed. Maybe the RHS is not convergent when $h\rightarrow 0$,so the conclusion is written in this form.

Comment: Are you seggesting using the $o(h)$ language?

Comment: *In the integral expression*, $h$ really is fixed. Bringing the $1/h$ inside the integral doesn't give you the derivative since we're not taking a limit, but it gives you something *close* to the derivative at $x$, and you can quantify how close by using the definition of derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it suffices to consider the case that $f$ is a non-decreasing function.

For $0 < h < b-a$  is
$$
 \int_a^b |f(x+h)-f(x)| \, dx = \int_a^b (f(x+h)-f(x)) \, dx \\
= \int_{a+h}^{b+h} f(x) \, dx - \int_a^b f(x) \, dx 
= h f(b) - \int_a^{a+h} f(x) \, dx \\
\le h f(b) - \int_a^{a+h} f(a) \, dx  = h(f(b) - f(a)) \, .
$$
Similarly,
$$
\int_a^b |f(x+h)-f(x)| \, dx \le (-h)(f(b)-f(a))
$$
$-(b-a)< h < 0$, so that
$$
\frac{1}{|h|}\int_a^b|f(x+h)-f(x)| \, dx \leq f(b)-f(a)
$$
for $0 < |h| < b-a$.

Comment: Is it possible that the third equal sign should be a less or equal to?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: The function is only defined on $[a, b]$, but it was clarified in a comment that we set  $f(x) = f(b)$ for $x > b$, therefore $\int_b^{b+h} f(x) dx = h f(b)$.

Comment: Ahh, sorry! I did not see that comment. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: $f$ is increasing. Note that $f(x)=f(a)$ if $x<a$ and $f(x)>f(b)$
if $x>b$. Under this extension, $f$ is increasing over $\mathbb{R}$.
Consider the case that $h>0$. Recall that monotone function is integrable
over compact set $[a,b]$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\\
 & = & \int_{a}^{b}\left[f(x+h)-f(x)\right]dx\\
 & = & \int_{a}^{b}f(x+h)dx-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\\
 & = & \int_{a+h}^{b+h}f(x)dx-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\\
 & = & \int_{b}^{b+h}f(x)dx-\int_{a}^{a+h}f(x)dx\\
 & = & hf(b)-\int_{a}^{a+h}f(x)dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{h}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx & = & f(b)-\frac{1}{h}\int_{a}^{a+h}f(x)dx\\
 & \leq & f(b)-\frac{1}{h}\int_{a}^{a+h}f(a)dx\\
 & = & f(b)-f(a).
\end{eqnarray*}

Then, we consider the case that $h<0$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\\
 & = & \int_{a}^{b}\left[f(x)-f(x+h)\right]dx\\
 & = & \int_{a}^{a+h}f(x)dx-\int_{b}^{b+h}f(x)dx\\
 & = & f(a)h+\int_{b+h}^{b}f(x)dx\\
 & \leq & f(a)h+\int_{b+h}^{b}f(b)dx\\
 & = & f(a)h-f(b)h.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\frac{1}{|h|}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\leq f(b)-f(a)$.

In short, if we take $M=f(b)-f(a)\geq0$ at the very beginning, then
for any $h\neq0$, $\frac{1}{|h|}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\leq M$.

---

Case 2: $f$ is of bounded variation over $[a,b]$ and that $f(x)=f(a)$
if $x<a$, $f(x)=f(b)$ if $x>b$. Choose increasing functions $g_{1},g_{2}$
such that $f=g_{1}-g_{2}$ and $g_{i}(x)=g_{i}(a)$ if $x<a$ and
$g_{i}(x)=g_{i}(b)$ if $x>b$, for $i=1,2$. By Case 1, there exists
$M_{1}>0$ and $M_{2}>0$ such that $\frac{1}{|h|}\int_{a}^{b}|g_{i}(x+h)-g_{i}(x)|dx\leq M_{i}$
whenever $h\neq0$, for $i=1,2.$ We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \frac{1}{|h|}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\\
 & = & \frac{1}{|h|}\int_{a}^{b}\left|[g_{1}(x+h)-g_{1}(x)]-[g_{2}(x+h)-g_{2}(x)]\right|dx\\
 & \leq & \frac{1}{|h|}\int_{a}^{b}\left|g_{1}(x+h)-g_{1}(x)\right|dx+\frac{1}{|h|}\int_{a}^{b}\left|g_{2}(x+h)-g_{2}(x)\right|dx\\
 & \leq & M_{1}+M_{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Extend $f(x)=f(b)$ for $x\gt b$; then
$$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname*{Var}}
\begin{align}
h\,\Var_{[a,b]}(f)
&=\int_a^{a+h}\color{#C00}{\Var_{[a,b]}(f)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&\ge\int_a^{a+h}\color{#C00}{\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{b-a}h\right\rfloor}|f(x+(k+1)h)-f(x+kh)|}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1b}\\
&=\int_a^{a+\left\lfloor\frac{b-a+h}h\right\rfloor h}|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1c}\\
&\ge\int_a^b|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: integral of a constant over an interval of width $h$
$\text{(1b)}$: the variation is the supremum of such sums
$\text{(1c)}$: collect the essentially disjoint intervals into one
$\text{(1d)}$: $a+\left\lfloor\frac{b-a+h}h\right\rfloor h\ge b$

Therefore,
$$
\frac1h\int_a^b|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\le\Var_{[a,b]}(f)\tag2
$$